# What's the order of oxidising strength of the oxyacids of Chlorine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends

What I have been told is that the **acidity** of the four oxyacids of Chlorine increase in the order **$\ce{HOCl} < \ce{HClO2} < \ce{HClO3} < \ce{HClO4}$**.

I have also been told that the oxidising strength goes in the reverse order. In my knowledge acidic strength should increase with oxidising strength. Where am I going wrong?

For your reference, the Ka values of the acids are as follows:

1. $\ce{HOCl} = 2.9 \times 10^{-8}$
2. $\ce{HClO2} = 1.1 \times 10^{-2}$
3. $\ce{HClO3} = 5.0 \times 10^2$
4. $\ce{HClO4} = 1 \times 10^3$

Comment: Don't you mean the oxyacids $\ce{HClO}$, $\ce{HClO2}$, $\ce{HClO3}$, and $\ce{HClO4}$?

Answer (score 4):

For many acids, the proton $\ce{H+}$ is the oxidizing agent. For example, in the oxidation of zinc with $\ce{HCl}$, the oxidizing agent is $\ce{H+}$.

$$\ce{Zn + 2H+ -> Zn^{2+} + H2}$$

However, for some acids, the conjugate base (anion) is also an oxidant (and usually a more powerful oxidant than $\ce{H+}$. The oxyacids of chlorine are all oxidizing agents through their anions, as is nitric acid and some others:

$$\ce{Zn + 2H+ + 2OCl- -> Zn^{2+} + H2O + 2Cl-}$$

In the above example, hypochlorite is the oxidizing agent. For the oxyacids of chlorine and others, the strength of the oxidizing agent is independent of the strength of the acid.

Comment: Why exactly would the proton often times be a weak oxidizer and why exactly would the conjugate bases sometimes be good oxidizers? Isn't the formation of H2 entropically favorable?

Comment: Formation of $\ce{H2}$ is entropically favorable, but so is conversion of $\ce{2HOCl}$ to $\ce{H2O + 2Cl-}$ (three particles from 2). Additionally, you cannot ignore the contribution to spontaneity from *enthalpy*.